# Нахождения совпадений в listBox c#

Tags: c#

Есть код(типа):

```
 string f = textBox1.Text;
 for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!listBox1.Items[i].Equals(f))
                        listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(f)));
                }
```

На проверку существования элемента, если элемента нету в listBox то добавить, else нет)
Но проблема в том, что он сравнивает каждую строку и добавляет значение(Каждый раз при неверном слове), а мне нужно другое...
То есть, есть в listBox("Слово"),("Строка"), и я добавляю слово "Строка", и он добавит еще раз строку("Строка"), не пройдя все индексы, вопрос: Как мне сначала проверить все Items а потом уж делать вывод, добавлять или нет.
*По нажатию добавляю если что.*
**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((listBox1.Items as IList<object>).FirstOrDefault(item => item.Equals(f)) == null) 
{
  listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(f)));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но для лист бокса нету определения FirstOrDefault, может я что-то не понимаю ?

Comment: using System.Linq;

Comment: B. Vandyshev - Она уже есть, оно не работает.

Comment: if (!listBox1.Items.Any(item => item.Equals(f))

Comment: Блин может я точно не понимаю но, не Any, не FirstOrDefault нету, для лист бокса...

Comment: `LINQ` есть у коллекций, коллекция у `listbox` - `items`, у нее должно быть.

Comment: Items в ListBox IEnumerable, а не IEnumerable<T> для того, чтобы использовать Linq нужно сначала скастить к нужному типу .Cast<string>() таким образом if (!listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(item => item.Equals(f))

Comment: B. Vandyshev, Igor Спасибо вам, и тот, и тот ответ правильный)
Премного благодарен) Но я использую ответ B. Vandyshev)